# USB 2.0 Signal Integrity Test using EHCI HSET Software

Tags: testing, usb, signals

I am trying to test *USB 2.0 Signal integrity (Eye Diagram).*
For doing that, USB IF Forum lets you download the EHCI HSETT Software from their website.
However, I am not able to use it due to one persistent problem:
`No Host Controllers Found`

Even though I have tried reinstalling the software, checking that I have the right 64-bit version and loaded the compliance driver manually(which keeps showing that it has errors in the device manager), I still get the same error.
anyone that can help with getting this running?